# Share Dialog in React Native FBSDK got undefined result.isCancelled & result.postId

Tags: javascript, facebook, react-native, react-native-ios

I tried to use FBSDK for share link to Facebook!
i follow step from https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk
and here is my share code:

```js
shareLinkWithShareDialog() {
  var tmp = this;
  ShareDialog.canShow(this.state.shareLinkContent).then(
    function(canShow) {
      if (canShow) {
        return ShareDialog.show(tmp.state.shareLinkContent);
      }
    }
  ).then(
    function(result) {
      if (result.isCancelled) {
        alert('Share cancelled');
      } else {
        alert('Share success with postId: '
          + result.postId);
      }
    },
    function(error) {
      alert('Share fail with error: ' + error);
    }
  );
}
```

but i always got result like this:
[image]

then isCancelled always undefined! with postId still undefined too!
Anyone can tell me why? Im using react native 0.42 and fbsdk 0.5.0

Comment: Why would you need to know?

Comment: if not know that result object! Result always succesfull! i cant catch cancel post or post successful

Comment: _Why_ would you need to catch that?

Comment: it is one condition for do one more function in my app

Comment: And what would that "one more function" be?

Comment: All sorts of reasons why you might want to catch this, perhaps you're providing some user reward for their share. It does appear that shares via the in-app browser will always return an empty `result` object though.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug. I got this issue since more than 6 months. From what I remember, the `result.postId` is not available if you did the share from the iOS Facebook app. It works fine if:

1. You don't have the iOS Facebook app (the share is done via in-app browser on iOS),
2. You perform a share from Android (Facebook app or not)

My workaround was to remove the `result.postId` check:

```
 if (!result.isCancelled /*&& undefined !== result.postId*/) {
     __DEV__ && console.log("SUCCESS");
 } else {
     __DEV__ && console.log("FAILURE");
 }
```

Comment: it not work for me bro! I try to share without app Facebook!
And result.isCancelled always undefined! cancel post or post successful always return undefined isCancelled! Can u suggest me anyway else?

Comment: I'm afraid, I can't help you on that :(